# What does event.target refer to in this W3 schools modal example?

Tags: events, modal-dialog

I'm not understanding this example:

```
[code]
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h2>Modal Example</h2>

        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
        <button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

          <!-- Modal content -->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }



        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            alert("Mongoose");
        }
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
    [/code]
```

The part that I'm not understanding is:

```
if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

I would have thought that since it's supposed to be clicking outside the modal, that it would be

```
if (event.target !=modal)
```

What does event.target refer to?

Comment: I'm not sure how they figured out it clicked outside the modal.   event.target is supposed to refer to the element on which the event was triggered.   However,  how does it know that something outside the modal was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

In the W3schools code example, I think that the `modal` in `(event.target == modal)` is actually referring to the *var* **modal** (see below) which itself refers to the background *div id* **myModal**.

```
<!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
```

and:

```
// Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
```

(The *class* name of the div **myModal** in the W3schools example is also **modal**, which is really, really confusing).

The actual modal "box" div's class is **modal-content**.

The larger containing "background" div's class is **modal**, and it fills the remaining negative space in the browser window outside the modal box itself (see images below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEqn0.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd5K7.jpg

It knows something outside the modal box was clicked because it detects that the background div was clicked. The background div's *id* is myModal, which is stored in *var* modal, which is the `modal` in `(event.target == modal)`.

Note: I'm not a modal maven, so I may be off a bit in my understanding (if anyone has any corrections, feel free to comment or post a better answer), but I hope this points you in the right direction making sense of this confusing example.